# Нужно ли делать Service для запросов в случае Retrofit + RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Вопрос вот в чем, насколько я понимаю ретрофит не реализует никаких сервисов. Правильная практика считается когда все запросы реализуются с сервисе. Чтоб если какие то задержки или длинные данные, чтоб все дорабатывало как нужно в случае если приложение свернули или смахнули.

Я вот сейчас использую связку рх + ретрофит и подумал о том, что если вдруг будет задержка или длинный файл какой то и юзер свернет(+система убьет приложение) либо юзер смахнет его то как бы запрос останется не выполненым.

Так получается что в случае использования этой связки все равно нужно реализовывать ее в сервисе?

Так ведь?

Comment: если для вас так критично чтобы крайне долгая операция точно закончилась - то да, к примеру в onStop() у активити стартуйте сервис. который закончит выполнение задачи. так твиттер делает, если плохой интернет и ты сворачиваешь прилож. стартует форграунд сервис. и рх + ретрофит это просто средства. они к андроиду не привязаны. не будь у вас их, а допустим обычные треды и дефолтный хттп клиент, проблема оставалась бы той же

Comment: @SviatVolkov мне почему то казалось что ретрофит как то реализовывает сервис или что то такое...

Comment: нет, ретрофит ничего об андроиде не знает. это чисто джавовская либа